# Change dropdown value with Fastselect

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

In our project we have a country dropdown using Fastselect. We already use it for some time, but need to add more functionality. We need to set the dropdown manually after an API call. However I can't seem to find a way to do this. The documentation of this plugin is almost nonexistent.

The dropdown is a select with options inside with isocodes as values.

```
<option value="DE">Germany</option>
```

The general way of changing a dropdown value does not work:

```
$('select[name$="shippingAddress.countryIso"]').val("DE");
$('select[name$="shippingAddress.countryIso"]').change();
```

So in short: Anyone know how to change a dropdown value programmatically with jquery using the fastselect plugin?

---

**Check the comments for fix/workaround**

Comment: It doesn't appear this is possible with the library you're using. If you check line 366 of [the source](https://github.com/dbrekalo/fastselect/blob/master/src/fastselect.js) you can see there is a `setSelectedOption()` function, but it is not publically accessible. I'd suggest using another library as this one seems very ill thought out. I'd recommend Select2

Comment: I would not recommend fastselect to anyone now. It was implemented for the requirements a good year ago. Seems like ...val("DE"); seems to work, but it is not visually changed. So I got the specific <option> and take the text and copied it to the designated area where fastselect shows it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any method/function to do this but you can use this code after popup dropdown.

```
$(".fstResultItem").eq(yourOptionIndexHere).trigger("click");
```

Hope this help you